# Mongo connect failed

Tags: java, mongodb

I got following error while connectiong to mongodb

> MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5
>
> connecting to: test Mon Jan 31
>
> 12:12:09 Error: couldn't connect to
>
> server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1154
>
> exception: connect failed

I removed mongodb and re-install mongodb-stable
It works fine for that day and next day got above error again.

Few times I tried to  re-install mongodb-stable still getting same error.

I am using latest pkg

deb http://downloads.mongodb.org/distros/ubuntu 10.4 10gen

I tried another way i.e tried to connect to other machines mongodb
i.e mongo otherMachinseIPAddress

mongo connection done successfully

But when i execute my program I got following error

> WARNING: jmx registration error,
>   continuing
>   javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   com.mongodb:type=ConnectionPool,host=tushar-desktop/127.0.1.1_27017
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:467)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1520)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:986)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:938)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:516)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.get(DBPortPool.java:62)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._set(DBTCPConnector.java:458)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.(DBTCPConnector.java:46)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.Mongo.(Mongo.java:137)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.Mongo.(Mongo.java:123)
>     at
>   com.mongodb.Mongo.(Mongo.java:90)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.LinkedinServiceImpl.(LinkedinServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.LinkedinServiceImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$d7de1b7.newInstance()
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.cache.CacheHelper.(CacheHelper.java:30)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.cache.CacheHelper$$FastClassByGuice$$35d2e084.newInstance()
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.services.impl.CachingServiceImpl.(CachingServiceImpl.java:32)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.services.impl.CachingServiceImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$de537f14.newInstance()
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.services.impl.LenseServiceImpl.(LenseServiceImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.services.impl.LenseServiceImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$21e1222c.newInstance()
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:804)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:754)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:793)
>     at
>   com.info.link.server.callbacks.LenseCallbackImpl.(LenseCallbackImpl.java:30)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
>     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Please help me.

Comment: do you see the instance running?(ps aux | grep mongo) which system do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mongod process is clearly not started. Try executing:

service mongodb start

Then try connecting again.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mongod` process is not running.

In one terminal window start mongo with:

```
$ mongod
```

Then connect to the mongo sheep with:

```
$ mongo
```